# Mongo aggregation create custom field based on others

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have order docs that look like this (this is a pseudo collection but I think it should illustrate enough):

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectID,
  status: String
  items: [{
    product: ObjectID
  }]
}
```

And product collection:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectID,
  status: String        
}
```

I am using aggregation to fetch a summary of orders.

```
[{
  $unwind: '$items'
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: 'products',
    localField: 'items.products',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'product'
  }
}, 
 {$unwind:'$product'},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    status: {
      $first: '$status',
    },
    products: {
      $addToSet: '$product.status'
    }
  }
}]
```

Right now this returns:

```
[ { _id: 57643e3a7d2dd411009e8869,
  status: 'processed',
  products: [ 'printing', 'done' ] } 
]
```

However my order status is really derived from a combination of its own status and that of its children products.

So I would like status to be the result of an expression that takes into account the products array such as:

```
status = ~products.indexOf('printing') ? 'in print' : '$status'
```

My setup is more complex but basically I need to look at the product statuses and then have some kind of overall status that represents their state or default to the original order status if certain conditions are not there.

Perhaps for another question I am also faced with the challenge that not all items have a related products (they get manually assigned in office) so I also need to check that my count of items is equal/not equal to product count and affect status from there. Phew.

I've been looking at $add and $filter but have not been able to get the whole setup going. I am doing this manually right now but would be nice to have Mongo do it.